# getting uri from android camera on all versions

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm trying to take a picture with my app, save it and retrieve the url. Currently I have:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) 
    {
        case TAKE_PICTURE:
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
            {
                File file = new File(getPath(data.getData()));

                Date dt = new Date(file.lastModified());
                String datum = dt.toLocaleString();

                Comment_Resource photo = new Comment_Resource(file.getAbsolutePath(), datum, true);


            }
            break;
        }
      }
}
```

this works on some phones but a lot of phones don't save the picture causing a nullpointer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```